# UserControl causes full postback

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have Placeholder within Update panel. On Page_Load I load user control via this code:

```
Control ctrl = LoadControl("~/UserControls/ListViewThumbs.ascx");
ucThumbs = (ListViewThumbs)ctrl;
ucThumbs.ID = "ucThumbs";


ucThumbs.SelectedIndexChanged += new UserControlSelectedIndexChanged(listView_SelectedIndexChanging);
ucThumbs.ItemDoubleClicked += new UserControlItemDoubleClicked(UserControlDoubleClicked);

ucPH.Controls.Clear();
ucPH.Controls.Add(ucThumbs);


AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = ucThumbs.UniqueID;
trigger.EventName = "ItemDoubleClicked";
updateMyDocs.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

Below aspx code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateMyDocs" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers = "true" EnableViewState = "true" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ucPH" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Clicking in usercontrol causes full postback. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Do you have your aspx code enclosed in <ScriptManager> ?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the update panel inside the userControl instead of outside it.

Update panels have issues like this when you put UserControls inside them